# What does it says the transconductance efficiency (gm/Id) in an amplifier?

Tags: amplifier, efficiency, fet, conductance

I understand the concept of the transconductance but it's not clear what does the transconductance efficiency (gm/Id) mean. Since gm is the variation of Id to the Vgs or vin voltage... What is the variation of Id to Vgs by Id???

Comment: I think the small signal gain (gm) is a function of the DC bias current (Id). So gm/Id tells you the rate of change of the gain as you vary the bias current. This is sort of half guess. Which is why I am not putting it in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a little unclear what you're actually asking. If you're asking why we care about transconductance efficiency, that I think I can answer.

If you're asked to design an amplifier, and you need a specific transconductance gm, the transconductance efficiency tells you the drain current you need to achieve that transconductance. That determines the current consumption and power dissipation of the amplifier.

Normally, the lower current consumption and less power dissipation, the happier your customer will be...

Comment: Yeah, I somehow missed the forest for the trees in my answer. I see someone [wrote a whole book](https://books.google.com/books?id=jdyr_ZYzunAC&) just about this Gm/Id design approach.

Answer (score 2):

Transconductance efficiency basically measures how much transconductance is produced for a given unit of bias current (as @mkeith correctly suggested).

You can also define it for a BJT common emitter as \$g_m/I_c=1/U_T\$ (so it's the inverse of thermal voltage), i.e. around 38.6 S/A at room temperature. Typically for a properly designed BJT it is constant (and high) over several decades of collector current.

MOSFETs aren't so nice. The transconductance efficiency of a MOSFET is alway less than that of a BJT and drops significantly in the [strong inversion](http://www.iue.tuwien.ac.at/phd/schrom/node84.html) region. Giving a summary of all that happens is a bit more than I signed up for here, but the essence is:

> The presence of effectively five regions or subregions of drain current
>   operation, which also controls transconductance, illustrates the complexity of analog CMOS design compared to bipolar transistor design, where a single region of exponential operation exists over as many as 10 decades of collector current.

As a numerical example, for bulk CMOS processes at room temperature, transconductance efficiency drops from approximately 25.7 S/A in weak inversion to 8.9 S/A at the onset of strong inversion, which is 35% of the weak inversion value, and it continues to drop after that.

You'll really want to read [Binkley's 2nd chapter](https://books.google.com/books?id=0AEPL-nC-r4C&pg=PA12) for all the details, equations for every MOSFET region etc.